# Is there a utility which converts json values to sql query

Tags: java, sql, json

Is there a utility which converts JSON values to SQL query

```
{
"table_name": "People",
"where": {
    "and": {
        "Name": "bob",
        "Age": 21
    },
    "or": {
        "Name": "alice"
    }
}
```

}

This will give me a result:

```
SELECT *
FROM People
WHERE (Name='bob' AND Age=21) OR (Name='alice')
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for an ORM.

Comment: There was a [post recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59233146/1428369)  asking for the other way round. This task is more straight forward, but some aspects apply. But if everything has the complexity of this example, I'd propose to create a pojo from the json and generate the sql by yourself, isn't much of a thing.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string. Because keys or string values should be wrapped by double quotes and if `where` is a JSON array, it should start with `[`.

Comment: LHCHIN : I have added the correct json

Comment: GMB: I don't want the ORM actually. my requirement is to get query string